# consul watch not propagating SIGTERM to child process

Tags: python, bash, consul, consul-kv

The below script is written in start.sh

```
trap 'kill -TERM ${consul_watch_pid} ${abc_pid} ${pqr_pid}; echo "start.sh got SIGTERM"; wait ${consul_watch_pid} ${abc_pid} ${pqr_pid}' TERM

    consul watch -http-addr=${hostIP}:7000 -type=key -key=${consul_kv_key} /consul_handler.sh 2>&1 &
    consul_watch_pid=$!

    /abc.sh &
    abc_pid=$!

    /pqr.sh &
    pqr_pid=$!

    sleep 5000d &
    wait $!

    wait ${consul_watch_pid} ${abc_pid} ${pqr_pid}

    echo 'start.sh exiting'
```

I want to forward TERM signal received by start.sh to /consul_handler.sh, /abc.sh and /pqr.sh
But /consul_handler.sh is not getting the SIGTERM. How to propogate the SIGTERM to /consul_handler.sh ?

Comment: `pkill --signal TERM 'consul_handler.sh'`?

Comment: Your issue seems to be that the `consul watch` does not give you back the PID for its client `consul_handler.sh`. Maybe it does in its output, then you could capture that into a variable. The other option is for your consul_handler.sh to land its running PID in a known file location you can read from your main script.